# Apple Music API, explicit content playback

Tags: ios, apple-music

I'm trying to use the new API from Apple, but when trying to play some songs using `setQueueWithStoreIDs(storeIds: [String])` method I noticed I couldn't play all of the songs in my queue. Trying to understand the problem was painful since the new APIs do not provide any errors. At the end I noticed I didn't have explicit content settings on in restrictions, but that took me some time. Apple Music actually does notify users when they try to play "explicit" flagged media if their app settings do not let them. Is there a way to do this in our apps?

Comment: Hey, Did anyone got the solution ? . Please let us know how you did it.

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same issue.
You need to make sure the ids you are adding to the queue belong to the same storefront where the user is.

Comment: The problem is more than just the storefront id. In the settings for the Music app, users can disable playback for content flagged as explicit, and in this case it doesn't matter if the storefront ids are correct, those songs fail to play silently.

Comment: Did any of you figure out on how to check whether a user is able to play a track or not (for explicit content)

Comment: Hey guys!, Have you find any solutions? I face the same problem.

Comment: I got the following errors, and also please find my question link here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49661397/lookup-song-by-isrc-in-apple-music-itunes

Comment: `FINISH Request: <MPCPlayerRequest: 0x283ff1600 label=MPMusicPlayerController playerPath=<MPCPlayerPath: route=<MPAVEndpointRoute: 0x282480e40 name=iPhone uid=LOCAL> bundleID=com.apple.Music [system media app] playerID=Music>> Response: (null) [0.049550s] error: Error Domain=MPRequestErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)" UserInfo={MPRequestUnderlyingErrorsUserInfoKey=(
    "Error Domain=MPCPlayerRequestErrorDomain Code=2000 \"Failed to get playing identifer\" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Failed to get playing identifer}"
)}`

Comment: `[Middleware] RRC <MPCPlayerRequest 0x283f8c000>: Request failed with error: Error Domain=MPRequestErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)" UserInfo={MPRequestUnderlyingErrorsUserInfoKey=(
    "Error Domain=MPCPlayerRequestErrorDomain Code=2000 \"Failed to get playing identifer\" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Failed to get playing identifer}"
)}`

Comment: Hi @IleshI am fetching Apple Music Playlists and tracks into my App, In my App settings screen I have added a Switch to show/hide Explicit songs of Apple Music. Can you suggest me how can I get to know wether the song is Explicit or not? Thank you in Advance.