# How to find Explicit Songs on Apple Music User Playlists iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, itunes, apple-music, apple-musickit

I am fetching all `Apple Music Playlists` and `Track lists` into my App using `AppleMusicAPI` (Refers https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applemusicapi). Also In my App's Setting screen I have added a `UISwitch` to allow `Explicit` contents of `Apple Music`.

I can able to get Explicit songs in below Search API and Top Tracks API using `attributes.contentRating` JSON key.

Top Charts API: https://api.music.apple.com/v1/catalog/us/charts?limit=20&offset=0&types=songs

Search API: https://api.music.apple.com/v1/catalog/us/search?limit=20&offset=0&term=Ana&types=songs

Can anyone suggest me how can I get to know wether the song is `Explicit` or not for `UserPlaylist` songs? Thank you!

Comment: The `contentRating` [Song.Attribute](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applemusicapi/song/attributes) seems to be what you are after

Comment: @Paulw11I can able to get contentRating from Top Tracks and Search Tracks API, but it's missing in UserPlaylists API. Here is the API details for both : Top Charts: https://api.music.apple.com/v1/catalog/us/charts?limit=20&offset=0&types=songs
Search: https://api.music.apple.com/v1/catalog/us/search?limit=20&offset=0&term=Ana&types=songs

Comment: Wouldn't you need to fetch the relevant tracks from the playlist's relationship to find out if a track is explicit?

Comment: Sorry @Paulw11, I didn't get you. Can you please elaborate this?

Comment: Perhaps you could add some more detail to your question.  As I understand it you say that the explicit attribute isn't included in the playlist data.  A playlist contains tracks.  You would need to retrieve the track to find out if it is explicit.

Comment: I have updated my question, please have a look and suggest me. Thanks!

Comment: What query are you executing to get the playlist?  What results do you get back - Can you show the request and a snippet of the returned JSON?

Comment: Thank you @Paulw11 for your suggestion. I have found Bool isExplicitItem in MPMediaItem Class for User Playlists.